# Sliding Panels by Erel/Corwin42

Tags: basic4android

The sliding panel is great, but I can't get the `Panels_Click` or `Panels_LongClick` to get raised.  Is there a workaround this?  I really need both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the touch is handled by Panels_Touch sub.
You can comment out Sub Panels_Touch and add Panels_Click and Panels_LongClick.
The user however will not be able to slide the panels with their finger.

Comment: Thanks.  I decided to use Slide up/down feature instead of longclick.